# Accurate computation of log error function difference

Tags: definite-integrals, numerical-methods

For information-theoretic purposes I am interested in computing $f(a, b)=-\log_2\left(\text{erf}(b) - \text{erf}(a)\right)$ where $b > a$ and $\text{erf}$ is the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).

Out-of-the box approximations (e.g [scipy.special.erf](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.special.erf.html)) fail because $\text{erf}$ rapidly approaches $\pm 1$ so that catastrophic cancellation occurs inside the logarithm while $f$ itself is actually really well-behaved. Does there exist a reasonably accurate and efficient approximation of $f$ directly?

To make the question even more elementary, we can also approximate

$$g(a, b) = \ln\int_a^b e^{-t^2}\mathrm{d}t$$

and find $f = cg + d$ for some $c,d \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: How accurate you want the result? Like an error bound.

Comment: You can use the complementary error function and write $erf(b)-erf(a)=erfc(a)-erfc(b)$.  In the regime you are interested in, $erfc$ is small and the cancellation disappears.

Comment: @Sonal_sqrt I'd say within 0.1 or 0.01 bits (that is, absolute error of $f$) is accurate enough.

Comment: @RossMillikan That is definitely a better approximation given floating point's density around $0$, but will still fail for relatively small inputs, e.g. $f(200-0.1, 200+0.1)$ fails on my machine with $\text{erfc}$ when it should output somewhere around $\approx 32500$.

Comment: Your problem there is that your numeric representation will not deal with $2^{32500}$  If you want to work with arguments that large you need you need something that handles large numbers.  [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=erfc%28200.1%29-erfc%28199.9%29) is quite happy computing the value before you take the $\log_2$ and gets about $10^{-17357}$

Comment: @RossMillikan That's why I'm asking if there's an efficient, *direct*, approximation. The function itself is well-behaved, it's only that its definition involves a microscopic number followed by a logarithm. That does not mean every approximation also has to use that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write $f(a,b)=-\log_2(\operatorname{erfc}(a)-\operatorname{erfc}(b))$.  That will eliminate the catastrophic cancellation.  If you want to use large arguments for $a,b$ you can use the expansion of $\operatorname{erfc}$ near $\infty$, which is
$$\operatorname{erfc}(x)\approx e^{-x^2}\pi^{-1/2}\left(\frac 1x-\frac 1{2x^3}+\frac 3{4x^5}+O(x^{-6})\right)$$
Let $c$ be the midpoint of your interval, so $c=\frac {a+b}2$ and pull out the factor $e^{-c^2}$.  You can take its logarithm analytically, getting $\log_2(e^{-c^2})=-\frac {c^2}{\log(2)}$ and none of the rest will overflow.

Putting it all together, we have 
$$c=\frac {a+b}2\\
f(a,b)=-\log_2(\operatorname{erfc}(a)-\operatorname{erfc}(b))\\
\approx -\log_2\left(e^{-a^2}\pi^{-1/2}\left(\frac 1a-\frac 1{2a^3}+\frac 3{4a^5}\right)-e^{-b^2}\pi^{-1/2}\left(\frac 1b-\frac 1{2b^3}+\frac 3{4b^5}\right)\right)\\
=\frac {c^2}{\log(2)}-\log_2\left(e^{-a^2+c^2}\pi^{-1/2}\left(\frac 1a-\frac 1{2a^3}+\frac 3{4a^5}\right)-e^{-b^2+c^2}\pi^{-1/2}\left(\frac 1b-\frac 1{2b^3}+\frac 3{4b^5}\right)\right)$$